# Ignore <script>-Tag in ajax html-result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to implement a service that can evaluate the mobile usability of targets (e.g. links,buttons, ...) from an uploaded website. To do so, the developer, who wants to test if his page is 'mobile-browser-capable', has to upload his site in a Zip-File. Afterwards the content gets extracted and the index.html of his site is loades into my 'evaluation_viewport'-DIV:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'index.html',   // the main page of the uploaded website
   success: function( result ) {
     $('#evaluation_viewport').html(result);
   }
});
```

The problem now is, that if the developers website has scripts it can cause problems and the div will stay empty. I want do ignore all the scripts and only load the layout (html + css + images) into my evaluation div. Any ideas how this could happen?

EDIT: thanks for the comment finally this worked

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.htm',
    success: function( result ) {
        var regex = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
        var resultWithoutScripts = result.replace( regex , "");
        $('#extractor_viewport').html(resultWithoutScripts);
    },
    async: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  result = replaceAll(result,"<script", "<div style='display:none'");
  result = replaceAll(result,"</script", "</div");


  function replaceAll(txt, replace, with_this) {
         return txt.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'),with_this);
   }
```